# Посчитать количество букв python

Tags: python

идет `input` где нужно ввести что угодно.

Как можно вывести потом сколько каких символов в предложении? без доп. модулей

Пример:

`input` - было введено : Футурама, то вывело бы

```
Ф - 1, У - 2 , Р - 1, Т - 1, А - 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = input('Введи что-нибудь: ')
for element in set(a):
    print("{} - {}".format(element, a.count(element)))
```

Comment: @Alioscha Z чет вывод не много не такой как я показал

Comment: @Alex добавьте в `print` ещё одним аргументом `end=', '`

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать стандартную библиотеку python. Там есть такая штука как `collections`. Выглядеть будет так:

```py
from collections import Counter
c = Counter("футурама") 
print(c)
```